# vscode this.~ call variable is not auto completed

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I made arraylist variable as global variable on home.ts
but I want to use arraylist variable on function.
I used to use it with autoimport like when I type just this.a ....then arraylist is on the list for me to pick up. but with my new laptop, it won't show up!
should I install certain plugin on vscode?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you cant reach `this.arraylist` from inside `once`

cuz `(snapshot)=>{}` binds to `.once` function

and when you write `this` it searchs the `this` of `once`